# Create MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to write a trigger so that it counts the total purchase amount(total_price) in the purchase_data table, that is, multiplies the quantity(product_count) from the purchase_data table by the price of the product(product_price) from the product table. It is necessary that after inserting or updating values in the purchase_data table, the total_price field is also updated, I hope I explained it clearly

[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtYhl.png)
[purchase_data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJNdg.png)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `calculate_total_price` AFTER INSERT ON `purchase_data` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE purchase_data pd
SET total_price = (
    SELECT p.product_price * NEW.product_count 
    FROM product p
    WHERE p.product_id = NEW.product_id
)
WHERE pd.purchase_id = NEW.purchase_id;
END
```

I tried to create some triggers but I have a constant error
`Can't update table 'purchase_data' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` I tried everything and failed to overcome it

code table purchase_data

```
CREATE TABLE `Purchase_data` (
  `purchasedata_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `purchase_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `product_count` INT NOT NULL,
  `total_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`purchasedata_id`),
  INDEX `Purchase_idx` (`purchase_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `Product_idx` (`product_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `Purchase`
    FOREIGN KEY (`purchase_id`)
    REFERENCES `DB_OnlineTrade`.`Purchase` (`purchase_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
    REFERENCES `DB_OnlineTrade`.`Product` (`product_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

code table product

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_pub` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `publisher_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `product_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  INDEX `Categoty_idx` (`category_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `Publisher_idx` (`publisher_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `Publisher`
    FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
    REFERENCES `DB_OnlineTrade`.`Publisher` (`publisher_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
    REFERENCES `DB_OnlineTrade`.`Category` (`category_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

table product:

```
product_id   product_cost
1                100  
2                250
3                370
..
```

table purchase_data:

```
purchasedata_id   product_count product_id  total_price
1                       2            3         370*2
2                       1            2         250*1
3                       3            1         100*3
..
```

I need a trigger that will calculate total_price after inserting or updating data. Omitted seemingly unnecessary columns in the tables.

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE for both tables. Provide some sample data (3-5 initial rows for each table, INSERT which your want to be processed by the trigger, desired final data state with detailed explanations). All data must be in well-formatted textual form, **not as a picture**!!

Comment: *but I have a constant error* You must use not UPDATE but `SET NEW.total_price = ( ... );` in BEFORE trigger.

Comment: I've painted everything now, but I don't really understand you. you can learn more

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) + [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) + [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `calculate_total_price` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `purchase_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.total_price = (
    SELECT product_price * NEW.product_count 
    FROM product
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id
    );
```

And the same for BEFORE UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers have limited utility for updating tables other than the one for which they fire. It's hard to tell you more without seeing the code foir *all* your triggers, and the SQL statements which fire them.

Comment: I need help creating the trigger implementation itself))